# Как отрисовать экран на весь размер, если переход на него находится внутри тела Scaffold?(Jetpack Compose)

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, navigation

В приложении я отрисовываю MainScreen на HomeActivity, у MainScreen есть TopAppBar и NavigationBar. С TopAppBar можно перейти на другой экран, который отрисуется на полный размер, перекрыв все что есть на MainScreen.
NavigationBar соответсвенно переключает экраны в теле Scaffold. Один из них - SearchScreen. На нём есть кнопка перехода на экран CreateScreen. Код который сделан сейчас, отрисовывает CreateScreen так же внутри тела Scaffold, мне же нужно чтобы он отрисовывался поверх MainScreen (т.е. без навигации сверху и снизу).
Я понимаю что CreateScreen находится в функции которая отрисовывает именно в теле Scaffold, но и в функцию которая отрисовывает MainScreen его не переместить, так как придется создавать новый контроллер который будет конфликтовать.
При этом мне нужно будет сделать так и на других экранах, по этому интересно какое решение будет наиболее оптимальным.

```
@Composable
fun BottomNavGraph(navController: NavHostController){
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screens.HomeScreen.name,
    ){
        composable(route = Screens.HomeScreen.name){
            HomeScreen()
        }
        composable(route = Screens.SearchScreen.name){
            SearchScreen(navController)
        }
        composable(route = Screens.WishlistScreen.name){
            WishlistScreen()
        }

        composable(route = Screens.CreateScreen.name) {
            CreateScreen()
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun MainNavGraph(navController: NavHostController){
    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screens.MainScreen.name,
    ){
        composable(route = Screens.MainScreen.name){
            MainScreen(navController)
        }
        composable(route = Screens.SettingsScreen.name){
            SettingsScreen(navController)
        }
    }
}
```

HomeActivity:

```
val navController = rememberNavController()
MainNavGraph(navController)
```

MainScreen:

```
@Composable
fun MainScreen(navController: NavHostController){
    val navControllerBottomBar = rememberNavController()
    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            TopAppBarContent(navController)
        },
        bottomBar = {
            BottomBarContent(navControllerBottomBar)
        }
    ) {
        Surface(modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(it),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(20.dp),
            color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.inverseOnSurface,
        ) {
            BottomNavGraph(navControllerBottomBar)
        }
    }
}
```

SearchScreen:

```
@Composable
fun SearchScreen(navController: NavHostController) {
    var textState by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    Button(
       onClick = { navController.navigate(Screens.CreateScreen.name) }
    ) {

    }
}
```

Comment: Все рисуется в NavHost (зачем их у вас 2 непонятно). NavHost располагается в Scaffold, где у вас есть топбар. NavHost всего лишь меняет свое содержимое в пределах своего размера. Не хотите топбар - не пихайте его в базовый Scaffold. Вообще Scaffold не является базовым layout приложения. Это просто один из. Например при боковой навигации можно сделать общий Scaffold с боковой панелью, а внутри на каждой нужной странице с баром - свой Scaffold с баром. Так и при нижней навигации топбар нужен на тех страницах, где он нужен. Хотя никто не запрещает таскать спец флаг "скрой топбар"